# Highcharts : using JSON data as label to xaxis

Tags: json, highcharts

I want to give name to xaxis as the data coming from JSON which will change dynamically
following is the code but it not labeling xaxis with the values store in key[obj] :

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: function(){
        var data;
        var obj = data[$("#host").val()].stats_vol.result.sectoutput;
        for(var key in obj){
            data.push({
                name: key[obj],
                categories : key[obj]
         })
        };
        return data;

},
```

Can anyone please help to make this code work ??

Answer (score 2):

Use setCategories method to update dynamically:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
```

**Update**
[Here is working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/p5debep6/5/)